# Не работает onClick у кнопки

Tags: reactjs

Пишу сайт на react js. У меня есть основной модуль App, из него я вызываю модуль ShowForm, который при вызове открывает модальное окно, с данные. В подвале окна есть кнопка "Сохранить изменения", при нажатии на которую должна выполнятся функция componentDidMount, но у меня кнопка не работает, и, к сожалению, ничего не отрабатывает. Тут внедрена библиотека Bootstrap, и само модальное окно построено с её помощью

Раньше, когда не внедрял ещё Bootsrtrap, у меня был просто тег , который также открывался по нажатию кнопки. у тега  было событие onSubmit(), которое правильно отрабатывало, по нажатию кнопки "Сохранить изменения"

В своем новом проекте я тоже пытался поставить  и ему событие onSubmit(), но не работает. Просто ничего не происходит.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class ShowForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.initialState = {
      TaskName: this.props.task.TaskName,
      User: this.props.task.User,
      Date: this.props.task.Date,
      Weight: this.props.task.Weight,
      Number: this.props.task.Number,
      Periodicity: this.props.task.Periodicity,
      SMARTTask: this.props.task.SMARTTask,
      GUID: this.props.task.GUID
    };
    this.state = this.initialState;
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { TaskName, Date, Weight, Number, Periodicity } = this.state;
    const month = Date.substr(6, 4) + '-' + Date.substr(3, 2)
    return (
      <div className='modal fade' id="modal-form-element" data-bs-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="modal-form-element-label" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id='modal-form-element-label'>Цель номер: {Number}</h5>
              <Button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ></Button>
            </div>
            <div className='modal-body'>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor='TaskName' className="col-sm-8 col-form-label">Наименование задачи</label>
                <div className="col-sm-0">
                  <textarea value={TaskName} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name='TaskName' className="form-control" placeholder="Наименование" id="TaskName"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor='Weight' className="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Вес</label>
                <div className="col-sm-0">
                  <input value={Weight} onChange={this.handleChange} type="number" name='Weight' className="form-control" id="Weight" placeholder="Число" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor='Number' className="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Номер задачи</label>
                <div className="col-sm-0">
                  <input value={Number} onChange={this.handleChange} type="number" name='Number' className="form-control" id="Number" placeholder="Число" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor='Date' className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Месяц</label>
                <div className="col-sm-0">
                  <input value={month} onChange={this.handleChange} type="month" name='Date' className="form-control" id="Date" placeholder="Число" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor='Periodicity' className="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Периодичность</label>
                <div className="col-sm-0">
                  <select value={Periodicity} onChange={this.handleChange} name='Periodicity' className="form-select" id='Periodicity'>
                    <option value="month">Месяц</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <Button type="Добавить" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.props.componentDidMount(this.state)}>Сохранить изменения</Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div >
    )
  }
}

export default ShowForm
```

я решил переписать код и сделать в этом же модуле обращение в серверу

```js
class ShowForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.initialState = {
      TaskName: this.props.task.TaskName,
      User: this.props.task.User,
      Date: this.props.task.Date,
      Weight: this.props.task.Weight,
      Number: this.props.task.Number,
      Periodicity: this.props.task.Periodicity,
      SMARTTask: this.props.task.SMARTTask,
      GUID: this.props.task.GUID
    };
    this.state = this.initialState;
    this.saveChanges = this.saveChanges.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  saveChanges() {
    const url = 'http://xxxxxxxxx/';
    const data = JSON.stringify(this.state);
    this.sendData(url, data);
  }

  async sendData(url, data) {
    const responce = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    })

    if (!responce.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Ошибка по адресу ${url}, статус ошибки: ${responce.status}`);
    }
    return responce.body;
  }

  render() {
    const { TaskName, Date, Weight, Number, Periodicity } = this.state;
    const month = Date.substr(6, 4) + '-' + Date.substr(3, 2)
    return (
      <div className='modal fade' id="modal-form-element" data-bs-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="modal-form-element-label" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id='modal-form-element-label'>Цель номер: {Number}</h5>
              <Button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ></Button>
            </div>
            <div className='modal-body'>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor='TaskName' className="col-sm-8 col-form-label">Наименование задачи</label>
                <div className="col-sm-0">
                  <textarea value={TaskName} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name='TaskName' className="form-control" placeholder="Наименование" id="TaskName"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor='Weight' className="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Вес</label>
                <div className="col-sm-0">
                  <input value={Weight} onChange={this.handleChange} type="number" name='Weight' className="form-control" id="Weight" placeholder="Число" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor='Number' className="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Номер задачи</label>
                <div className="col-sm-0">
                  <input value={Number} onChange={this.handleChange} type="number" name='Number' className="form-control" id="Number" placeholder="Число" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor='Date' className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Месяц</label>
                <div className="col-sm-0">
                  <input value={month} onChange={this.handleChange} type="month" name='Date' className="form-control" id="Date" placeholder="Число" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor='Periodicity' className="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Периодичность</label>
                <div className="col-sm-0">
                  <select value={Periodicity} onChange={this.handleChange} name='Periodicity' className="form-select" id='Periodicity'>
                    <option value="month">Месяц</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <Button variant='primary' className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.saveChanges}>Сохранить изменения</Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div >
    )
  }
}
```

но все равно почему-то не работает событие onClick у кнопки. Вообще не понимаю в чем проблема(

Comment: Замените `onClick={this.props.componentDidMount(this.state)}` на `onClick={() => this.props.componentDidMount(this.state)}` однока не понятно, зачем вам вызывать системный метод и я не уверен, что он сработает

Comment: я уже так пробовал не работает. Я также делал отдельную функция, где уже вызывал componentDidMount, но все равно не работает.

Comment: Вообще, componentDidMount вызывается автоматически при установке компонента в DOM. Зачем вы хотите еще раз его вызвать? Создайте свой кастомный метод и вызывайте его.

Comment: попробовал создать свой, но также ничего не получается(

Comment: Понатыкайте консоль.логов. посмотрите, что передается в качестве пропсов, нажимается ли кнопка, срабатывает ли метод в родителе, может ошибки есть.

Comment: в качестве пропсов все правильно передается. Когда я просто нажимаю на кнопку для открытия данной формы, то весь код обрабатывается, также хорошо заходит в onClick и весь код правильно обрабатывается. Но если уже сам нажимаешь на кнопку, то событие ничего не работает, нигде отладка не останавливается, просто ничего не происходит. Я ни понимаю, почему так

Comment: `submit` - событие [html form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), вы используете 'div', кроме этого, если вы `onClick` пробрасываете через пропсы, вы уверены, что не теряется [контекст выполнения](https://learn.javascript.ru/bind)?

Answer (score 1):

> у меня кнопка не работает, и, к сожалению, ничего не отрабатывает

Вот пример с использованием метода который "привязывается" к `this` класса в конструкторе, а потом передается кнопке как обработчик.

Добавил еще один вариант "привязки" `this` к функции...

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  act(o) {
    alert('N = ' + o.n)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Test act={this.act} />
    )
  }
}
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      n: 1
    }
    this.test = this.test.bind(this)
  }
  test() {
    this.props.act(this.state)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.test}>Test 1</button>
        <button onClick={(_ => _ => this.props.act(this.state)).call(this)}>Test 2</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```